What's the difference between workbench.iconTheme and workbench.productIconTheme settings in Visual Studio Code?

When reviewing the configuration .json file I realized that there are two very similar options in terms of the appearance of the icons, workbench.productIconTheme and workbench.iconTheme.
I would like to understand what the difference is since the information I have found on this is a bit confusing.
Mainly because on the official Visual Studio Code page it is defined that Workbench refers to the general UI of Visual Studio Code which encompasses the following UI components:

title bar, activity bar, sidebar, panel, editor group, status bar

and I understand that the two options/settings refer to the same thing, the workbench.
I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what each of the options refers to and what effects it has on the appearance of Visual Studio Code.
I ask this since when modifying the settings there is no visible change, no visible difference. The only setting that make changes is the workbench.productIconTheme as changes the icons on the left bar of the app itself.
workbench.iconTheme does nothing visible.

Have you done any modification to the values to see what they apply and how they may supersede or conflict with each other?

Done. No visible difference. The only setting that make changes is the workbench.productIconTheme as changes the icons on the left bar of the app itself. workbench.iconTheme does nothing visible, perhaps is "deprecated"?

That info would be good in the question body. This site is quite different from a threaded forum. Adding info to your question is a good way to get good answers.

As the description of the workbench.iconTheme mentions, it:

Specifies the file icon theme used in the workbench or null to not show any file icons.

So it changes these file and folder icons:

Shown for example in file explorer, in editor tabs next to file names, etc. - based on file or directory type. The theme on the picture above is Material Theme. See also docs for more info.

Meanwhile, workbench.productIconTheme, as you noticed, refers to various other icons all over the workbench. This would be the corresponding Material Product Icons theme:

See also docs.

For some reason Visual studio Code did not update the file structure icons, so it was impossible for me to see the changes. Fixed by restarting VSCode. Thank you very much for clarifying it. Sometimes I forget the basic rule of the IT department: before everything, reboot.
